# Why does python require you to acquire a lock before waiting on a condition

Tags: python, multithreading, python-internals

Python has a threading Object called `Condition` which blocks a thread waiting until another thread calls `notifiy()` or `notify_all()` on it. Before calling the `wait()` method however, you must first call `acquire()` to acquire the internal lock. the `wait()` method then releases the lock and waits to be notified, after which it will proceed to reacquiring the lock and you can run some code that needed to be thread-safe. My question is why doesn't the `Condition` object just acquire the lock automatically internally when you call the `wait()` method:

#### Python threading documentation

> Other methods must be called with the associated lock held. The `wait()` method releases the lock, and then blocks until another thread awakens it by calling `notify()` or `notify_all()`. Once awakened, `wait()` re-acquires the lock and returns. It is also possible to specify a timeout.

So in this code I acquire the lock, wait method immediately releases it and then after it's notified it acquires it again then i eventually release it.

```py
lock = threading.Lock()
condition = threading.Condition(lock=lock)
...
condition.lock()    # acquire the lock
condition.wait()    #  waiting for another thread to notify me
condition.release() # release the lock
```

why doesn't the `wait()` call just wait and then acquire the lock once it has been notified I don't see why I am acquiring the lock that it will then release

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but I'm excited to see if others do. This is a good question. :)

Answer (score 9):

If you weren't holding the lock, the thing you're waiting for could happen *before* you started waiting for it.

Say you've got a homebrew message queue implemented with a `collections.deque`, a `threading.Lock`, and a `threading.Condition` variable.

Thread A wants to read an item from the queue, so it grabs the `lock`, checks the `deque`, and there's no item. Thread A calls `condition.wait` to wait for another thread to put something in.

Thread B grabs the `lock`, calls `deque.append`, and calls `condition.notify`. Thread A is now scheduled to wake up because of the `condition.notify` call.

Imagine if thread A could release the `lock` before calling `condition.wait`. In that case, thread B might append its item and call `condition.notify` before thread A starts waiting. Thread A would never wake up.

Comment: Great answer. Just adding a note: this kind of "wait forever" action can still happen with the lock guard-- it just ensures that the actions that happen between `lock` and `wait` wont cause the executing thread to miss a message. If thread B updates a message before thread A ever gets to the `lock` call, then thread A could still be stuck waiting indefinitely.

Comment: @flakes: If thread B put a message in before thread A grabbed the lock, then thread A would see the message and not wait. It's still possible to get an infinite wait if you screw things up and make a bug, of course.

Comment: "If thread B put a message in before thread A grabbed the lock, then thread A would see the message and not wait" That was not my understanding. `notify` will only wake up threads if they have already acquired the `lock` and are waiting. If you lock and wait after the previous `notify` you will block the thread until the next `notify` invocation is made. This is ensured because the notifier thread also has to acquire the same lock.

Comment: @flakes: But thread A would grab the lock and then *not* wait, because it would see the element thread B put in. It wouldn't even *call* `wait`, so there would be no need to wake A. If thread A waited unconditionally, that would be a bug in thread A's code.

Comment: Ah your talking specifically for your deque example, and not a general case? (I.e. message not as the notify call, but as values in a container). I believe we're in violent agreement.

Comment: just as a clarification (years later). once you acquire the lock that's when the check should happen right. the code in my question seems unrealistic I believe now because I'm supposed to acquire the lock and *then* decide whether I want to wait or not. that's what I believe was my confusion. the scenario of lock and immediately doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @masonCherry: Yeah, you need to hold the lock while you check whatever shared resource you're checking.